# Why are %rbp and %rax invalid operands for movl?

Tags: c, x86-64, inline-assembly, att, mov

I'm trying to put the value of `%rbp` into the `%rax` register using `__asm__` so that I can get a reference to the stack frame that won't be changed when I create an external variable.

I'm using the following code to do this:

```
int some_variadic_function(int n, ...)
{
    __asm__("movl %rax, %rbp");
    return 0;   
}


int main() {
    some_variadic_function(3, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try and compile this with clang I get the following error:

```
using_rbp.c:4:13: error: invalid operand for instruction
    __asm__("movl %rax, %rbp");
            ^
<inline asm>:1:7: note: instantiated into assembly here
        movl %rax, %rbp
             ^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This seems to be implying that I can't put `%rbp` directly into `%rax`. Is that's what happening, or is there another issue with this code?

For reference, I'm on Mac with `x86-64` hardware.

Comment: Size mismatch.  `movl` is 32-bit, so needs `%eax`, and `%ebp` as operands.  `movq` will take the 64-bit registers.

Comment: Oh weird! When I looked it up it said `movl` was for 64bit. Am I completely wrong, or does it differ?

Comment: You are completely wrong.  AT&T size suffixes are unambiguous for integer operands, and `l` means 32-bit.  (For x87 FP, unfortunately `flds` is 32-bit single, `fldl` is 64-bit double.)  For `movl`, the `l` definitely means 32-bit operand-size.  When a register implies the size, just omit the size override like Intel syntax does, it's a waste of typing.  (Except maybe with inline asm where you're using `%0` or `%[var]` operands that the compiler will expand, then it's a good check that your operands have the type-width you intended.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a whole bunch of mistakes.  Let's take them one by one:

1. In AT&T assembly syntax for x86, if you provide a size suffix on the instruction, it must match the sizes inferred from the operands.  Size suffixes are almost always unnecessary for x86 (the only case I can think of, offhand, where they're needed is when the source operand is an immediate value and the destination is memory): I recommend leaving them out unless the assembler complains about their absence.
2. In AT&T assembly syntax, the destination comes *second*; `mov %rax, %rbp` copies RAX into RBP, not the other way around.
3. In GNU-style inline assembly, `%` begins an escape sequence (like in `printf`); to write a literal register name you have to double the percent sign. This is why you are getting an error from clang, rather than from the assembler.
4. GNU-style inline assembly must be annotated with "operand constraints" so the compiler understands what you are doing.  You cannot simply move a value into RAX and expect that to become the return value.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.3.0/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html -- read *all* of this manual section, not just the summary page I linked to.
5. In the 64-bit System V ABI for x86, `%rbp` is an ordinary general-purpose register, not a "frame pointer".

The correct way to do what you were trying to do is

```
long some_variadic_function(int n, ...)
{
    long rv;
    __asm__("mov %%rbp, %0" : "=r" (rv));
    return rv;
}
```

However, this must be compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` or the return value will be garbage.

You are probably suffering from the infamous [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Ask a new question about the thing you were *originally* trying to do, not about the details of your attempted solution to the problem, and we can probably be more helpful.

Comment: I had a different error before that using `movl` fixed, so I assumed that wasn't the issue! Thank you, changing to `mov` let it compile. You're right, this is an XY, problem, I've posted a question about it previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76028121/can-i-get-rsp-with-inline-assembly. Basically, I want to access stack arguments without using `varg` and any `built_ins`. It's an exercise on codewars that supposed to teach you about stack frames.

Comment: I think my answer to the other question is "write the entire function by hand in assembly language in a `.s` file, the compiler is only getting in your way here". And that would also mean you could use Intel syntax if you want.

Comment: *I recommend leaving them out unless the assembler complains about their absence.* - Beware that until the last couple years, GAS would assemble `add $1, (%rdi)` without complaint as `addl`.  Now it still just warns, not errors, unless you use Intel-syntax mode.  Only for `mov $1, (%rdi)` does it error on the ambiguous operand-size, any other operation uses 32-bit as a default operand size.  I think I read once that historical Unix assemblers had this default, so I guess that's why GAS only errors on ambiguity in Intel-syntax mode.  (Clang is better, erroring on ambiguity even in AT&T mode.)

Comment: @zwol The problem is, it has to be in C, because it's being sent to an external server for compilation in C. I'm not allowed to add source files, it's a single file! From the discussions I've had, this is a silly thing to do, however, I am learning a lot... so perhaps it's not so silly!

Comment: @Connor: You can write whole functions in asm by putting an `asm("...")` statement *at global scope*, outside any function.  The "template string" in that case should define a label like `asm("foo:  lea (%rdi, %rsi, 2), %eax; ret");`, and the C should declare a prototype for the function like `int foo(int, int);`.  (No need to use `.globl foo` since it only needs to be visible within this one file.)